# OneHotEncoderunexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to run a [face recognizer](https://github.com/anhtuhsp/Face-Recognition-with-InsightFace/tree/master/) program. In the read me section, it was written that I should run train_softmax.py but in the code, there is this section:

```
# Encode the labels
le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(data["names"])
num_classes = len(np.unique(labels))
labels = labels.reshape(-1, 1)
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
labels = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(labels).toarray()
```

that raises the error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'
```

but changing 'categorical_features' to 'categories' or using ColumnTransformer, raises other errors. what should I do?t

Answer (score 0):

replace this whole block

```
#le = LabelEncoder()
#labels = le.fit_transform(data["names"])
#num_classes = len(np.unique(labels))
#labels = labels.reshape(-1, 1)
#one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
#labels = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(labels).toarray()
```

to below will yield the same output as `LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder` combine

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

num_classes = len(np.unique(data["names"])) 

ct = ColumnTransformer([('myCT', OneHotEncoder(), [0])])
labels = ct.fit_transform(df[['names']])
```

Comment: if by df, you mean data. it also raises TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @Moe: yes, it is the convention in pandas world that `df` is the working dataframe which is `data` in your case. If it raises TypeError, there is something else in the other part of the code trigger it. I am sorry I could not help you further.